# How can I stop my jQuery slideshow glitching?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've been working on a slideshow from a template I found online, and although everything works great when the page loads, if I leave the page open with the slideshow running in the background while I'm visiting other sites or using other programs, I often come back to find it glitching.

The timing seems to speed up drastically and the slides don't fade into each other, they'll just cut really fast. Annoyingly, this is an intermittent problem, and usually happens when the webpage has been running in the background for a while.

Can anyone see any obvious errors in my code or a reason why this might be occurring?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

https://jsfiddle.net/87dLnuz9/1/

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 5000);
```

```css
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    height: 100%; 
    padding: 38% 0; 
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center
}

#slide-one {
    background-image: url("https://www.openaccessgovernment.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/dreamstime_xxl_2584709-scaled.jpg");  
}

#slide-two {
    background-image: url("https://i.natgeofe.com/n/80b97fe3-c0fb-40a6-a6a6-88b5c3bb9d30/01-lion-populations-nationalgeographic_1777804.jpg");
}
  
#slide-three {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/YB6aQqKZBVjtt3PuDSkJKe.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slide-one" class="slide">
    </div>
    <div id="slide-two" class="slide">
    </div>
   <div id="slide-three" class="slide">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I' suggest pausing the slide show when the tab loses focus. Seems like a waste of resources to keep it running

Comment: I see your point, but on the webpage there are two parallel slideshows with slight time differences that drift slightly further apart as they progress. They need to be kept running

Comment: You can save current state, pause and resume from the saved state when tab regains focus

Comment: @Jack1991 I'm not sure what the problem is that is creating the speeding, but maybe you can try https://jsfiddle.net/w1z90Lg6/

Comment: Makes sense. Do you know how I can do that? I found the jQuery in a template and what you're suggesting is outside my ability level. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen thanks, I'll try that one! :)

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen - I tried the new code but it still seems to speed up and go completely out of sync, I've no idea why. It's only when the page has been left for a period of time when I switch windows or tabs